# Mousover parent DIV to change child DIV backgrounds

Tags: javascript, mouseover, background-color

I have a parent DIV that contains three other small DIV's.  I would like to change the background colors of the three child DIV's when I hover or mouseover the parent DIV.  Is it possible to do this in javascript or jquery?

```
<div id="r1">  //Mousover

<div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color
<div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color
<div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color

</div>
```

Comment: Tim gave the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in CSS as well,

but from what I understand you want to do, this is how you can achieve that in JQuery:

```
<div id="r1" onmouseover='changeBg(this);' onmouseout='revertBg(this);'>  //Mousover

    <div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color
    <div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color
    <div class="bx"></div>  //Change background color

</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function changeBg(div){
       $(div).children('.bx').attr('background-color', '#AAAAAA');
    }
    function revertBg(div){
       $(div).children('.bx').attr('background-color', '#BBBBBB');
    }    <script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do this with javascript, you can just use CSS

```
div#r1:hover div.bx{ background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript:

```
$('#r1').hover(function(){ $(this).addClass('r1hovered'); });
```

And add that to your CSS:

```
.r1hovered .bx { background-color: red; }
```

Source : http://api.jquery.com/hover/